# Splitting row into row per month and splitting number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of events with a start_date column (EV200_EVT_START_DATE) and end_date column (EV200_EVT_END_DATE). Events could span more than one month.

I also have a table with every day of every year (which i think could help).

I want to be able to split the revenue by month- so essentially i think i need join each event with each corresponding month/year it overlaps. I then need to calculate the number of total days the event runs for and divide the number of event days in the "joined" month.

```
Event Table (EV200_EVENT_MASTER)
===
EV200_EVT_START_DATE,EV200_EVT_END_DATE,EV200_EVT_ID
15/01/2012,17/01/2012,1
15/01/2012,15/02/2012,2
15/01/2012,15/03/2012,3

Calendar Table (EV001_MSTR_DATE_SCHED)
===
EV001_ISO_DATE
01/01/2012
02/01/2012
...
01/01/2021
02/01/2021

Output (something like)
===
EV200_EVT_START_DATE,EV200_EVT_END_DATE,EV200_EVT_ID,Year,Month,Days,Split
15/01/2012,17/01/2012,1,2012,1,2,1
15/01/2012,15/02/2012,2,2012,1,17,0.55
15/01/2012,15/02/2012,2,2012,2,14,0.45
15/01/2012,15/03/2012,3,2012,1,17,0.28
15/01/2012,15/03/2012,3,2012,2,29,0.48
15/01/2012,15/03/2012,3,2012,3,14,0.23
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the output you'd like? And the source table structure?

Comment: @diana i have added example of the input and output- thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

- an Event Table with an ID, StartDate, EndDate and Revenue
- a Days Table with an ID column being a date, with a row for each day of the year (over all years you are interested in)

Then this should give what you want. However, if there's an accountant involved somewhere they might have rules about when revenue is recognised...

```
Select
  Year(d.ID) As Year,
  Month(d.ID) As Month,
  Sum(e.Revenue/Cast((e.EndDate - e.StartDate + 1) As Decimal)) As RevenuePerMonth
From
  Event e
    Inner Join
  Days d
    On e.StartDate <= d.ID And e.EndDate >= d.ID
Group By
  Year(d.ID),
  Month(d.ID)
Order By
  1, 2
```

Edits

- Fixed RevenuePerDay to RevenuePerMonth as Terje pointed out
- Changed per your table names and column requirements.
- Update to avoid rounding errors (apologies for the trials in the comments)

Tested this time:

```
Select
  e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date,
  e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date,
  e.Ev200_Evt_Id,
  Year(d.Ev001_Iso_Date) As Year,
  Month(d.Ev001_Iso_Date) As Month,
  e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date - e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date + 1 As Days,
  Cast(Count(*) As Decimal)/Cast(e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date - e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date + 1 As Decimal) As Split
From
  Ev200_Event_Master e
    Inner Join
  Ev001_Mstr_Date_Sched d
    On e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date <= d.Ev001_Iso_Date And e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date >= d.Ev001_Iso_Date
Group By
  e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date,
  e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date,
  e.Ev200_Evt_Id,
  Year(d.Ev001_Iso_Date),
  Month(d.Ev001_Iso_Date),
  e.Ev200_Evt_End_Date - e.Ev200_Evt_Start_Date + 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d99bc/11/0

Comment: Isn't your RevenuePerDay really RevenuePerMonth?

Comment: holy s**t that's simple! i'll give it a try :)

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to decimal is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: wrapping the dates in cast(blah as decimal) worked. thanks- great solution- i massively overcomplicated things!

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Also noticed the days column should have had a +1 in it.

Comment: any idea why some results are .0000000000001 out? e.g. `2013-03-06 00:00:00.000, 2013-03-08 00:00:00.000, 27867, 2013, 3, 3, 0.9999999999999999999`

Comment: I've changed the answer to hopefully avoid rounding errors. Apologies for the false starts in the comments.